# Forward declaration of a forward-declared class member

Tags: c++

Is it possible to forward-declare a class declared in another forward-declared class?

Basically, I have something like this

```
//A.h
class A
{
...
    struct B
    {
    ...
    };
};
```

and now I want to declare another class like this

```
//Q.h

class A;
struct A::B;

class Q
{
    A::B* Foo();
};
```

Comment: Is it that hard to just compile the code above and try it out yourself?

Comment: @fontanini Ah. But does it work reliably? On all compilers? Is it legal according to the standard?

Comment: I tried that, naturally. Compiler says "use of undefined type A".

Comment: Just by trying to compile it, you can see it does not compile. Therefore: But does it work reliably? No, it does not compile. On all compilers? No, it does not compile. Is it legal according to the standard? No, it does not compile, therefore it can't be legal.

Comment: @fontanini “It does not compile, therefore it can’t be legal” – bullshit.

Comment: Ok, replace "can't" with "shouldn't", it's still the same.

Comment: @fontanini: There are many things that should compile and don't, and others that shouldn't compile and do. The result of a particular compiler is no guarantee at all.

Comment: @fontanini: others have already commented on the Standard compliance aspect, so I won't go there. I do agree with you that *work reliably* however is very quickly assessed when it fails the test!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot be done. To access the members of `A` it has to be defined, regardless of whether the member is a type, data or function.