# Forward-declare a class member typedef

Tags: c++, typedef, forward-declaration

I have in my header a `typedef` which is a member of class `cl1`

```
template <size_t d>
class my_wkspc::cl1 {
  public:
    typedef std::vector<real> table_t;
    ...
    typename my_wkspc::cl2<d>& getCl2() { return _cl2; }  // <------ Not yet used
    ...
  private:
    typename my_wkspc::cl2<d>& _cl2;  // <------ Not yet used
};
```

and I need that `typedef` for a class member and functions in class `cl2`

```
namespace my_wkspc {
template <size_t d>
class cl2 {
  public:
    typename cl1<d>::table_t& getTable() const { return _table; }
    ...
  private:
    typename cl1<d>::table_t& _table;
    ...
};
```

Now I also need to define `cl1` class members of type `cl2` (not yet implemented).
I think that I could forward declare `cl2`, and place any `cl1` member function requiring knowledge of `cl2` in a source file (PS: this would break my header-only classes).

**But can I place `cl2` class definition above `cl1`, with some kind of forward-declaration of `typedef std::vector<real> table_t`?**

In [Forward declare typedef within C++ class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966686/forward-declare-typedef-within-c-class) it is asked something similar (even more difficult, with reciprocal uses of `typedef`s), but the OP is very old, and answers (stating this is not doable) might exclude later alternatives.
A *late template instantiation* [is suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966775/2707864).

**Related**:

1. [Forward-declare a typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287578/forward-declare-a-typedef)
2. [Forward declaring a typedef for a template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586008/forward-declaring-a-typedef-for-a-template-class)
3. [Forward declare a class's public typedef in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836551/forward-declare-a-classs-public-typedef-in-c)
4. [Forward declaration of a forward-declared class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701732/forward-declaration-of-a-forward-declared-class-member)
5. [Forward declaration of a typedef in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c/804956#804956)
6. [Forward declaring a template's member typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870922/forward-declaring-a-templates-member-typedef)

Comment: To forward template class, you might do: `template <size_t> class cl2;`.

Comment: Problem is cyclic dependency between `cl1` and `cl2`. This is very strong coupling and you have two choices: break cycle, place both class templates in single header file and fight with forward declaration.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I know, and that is part of one option (I would call it a workaround in my case) I posted in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Make a traits class that defines `table_t` and little else.  Use it in both spots.

Forward declare templates.

```
template<std::size_t>class cl1;
template<std::size_t>class cl2;
template<std::size_t>struct table{
  using type=std::vector<real>;
};
template<std::size_t s>
using table_t=typename table<s>::type;
```

this assumes `ttable_t` actually depends on the template parameter.  If not, just make it a plain typedef/using statement.

Comment: Replacing the class member `typedef` with a separate class (or, in this case, adding the new class to the `typedef`/`using`) was an option.
I meant to avoid it, but it is on the map. Thanks.

Comment: @sancho.s you can only open a class once.